# How can numbers be boxed in?

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols

What is a simple way to write a numeral inside a square, or a rectangle if it is not a short numeral?

Comment: How about `\fbox{1234}`?

Comment: @user23623 Thanks

Comment: In OpTeX, use `\frame{1234}`. The first comment is only usable in LaTeX.

Comment: @wipet new (since 5 minutes ago) toy for you: https://texlive.net/run?%25%20!tex%20optex%20%0A%5Cframe%7B1234%7D%0A%5Cbye%0A

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you use tabular (same width) and lining (same height) digits, you can use `\fbox` with tweaked parameters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sqnum}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \settowidth{\dimen@}{#1}%
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}%
  \fbox{%
    \ifdim\dimen@>\fontcharht\font`0
      % just box the numbers
      #1%
    \else
      \makebox[\fontcharht\font`0]{#1}%
    \fi
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\sqnum{1} \sqnum{2} \sqnum{123}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we have an example where the dimension test implies the use of the `\makebox`?

Comment: @projetmbc Any single digit, because their natural width is less than the height.